How to hide flowbite drawer when page loads and only show when users click the button?
using flowbite drawer to show content. I'm showing to figure out how to hide the drawer when the page loads. i would like to have the drawer show only when the button is clicked.

   
   Show bottom drawer
   



    
    
  Bottom drawer
    
      
         
      
      Close menu
   
    Supercharge your hiring by taking advantage of our limited-time sale for Flowbite Docs + Job Board. Unlimited access to over 190K top-ranked candidates and the #1 design job board.
   Learn more
   Get access 
    
  

I have tried changing the values in the button class. Am I missing something to stop the drawer from appearing when the page is loading. I used this code edit: transition-transform left-0 top-0 -translate-x-full

Add translate-y-full class to the drawer from the bottom and this will help you to solve your issue
